# How does linkForSingleResource work?

Tags: spring, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I can understand this code finds the BookController because I do `@ExposesResourceFor(Book.class)` before BookController but how does it know which method/URL to resolve into?

```
entityLinks.linkForSingleResource(book).toUri();
```

and this resolves into `127.0.0.1:8080/books/5`

Does it just add /id to the url and doesn't check methods at all?

Comment: Well, the fact that information is available doesn't mean that it's easy to discover or understand, in particular for people new to a subject. So I decided to write a proper answer and removed my comments. Cheers and +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring HATEOAS documentation has a [chapter on EntityLinks](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.23.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#fundamentals.obtaining-links.entity-links) that shows an example.

The [documentation on ControllerEntityLinks](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/core/ControllerEntityLinks.html) contains more details about the expected URI structure. There needs to be one empty mapping for the collection and one mapping with an id path variable for individual resources.

```
@Controller
@ExposesResourceFor(Order.class)
@RequestMapping("/orders")
class OrderController {

  //The collection resource
  @RequestMapping
  ResponseEntity orders(…) { … }

  //Individual resources
  @RequestMapping("/{id}")
  ResponseEntity order(@PathVariable("id") … ) { … }
```

}

Comment: Thank you, turns out I didn't know how to read Java documentation with this implementation and interface classes being that separate.